# Ajax (get, parse) HTML table data from remote server, domain, site

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax, json

For illustration purposes:

:the html table data source = "example.com/html_page_source" (tableid="source")

:an xml file built from the above table data = "pretendco.com/xml_built_from_html_table

Hoping someone can illustrate exactly how (on pretendco's server) I build an xml file from the remote table's html page source (on example's server).

My experience here is relatively limited, so I'm not certain Ajax is the solution.
Thanks in-advance.  Greatly appreciated!

--john

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you want to use AJAX or even javascript here unless it absolutely has to be done while the user is viewing a page rather than before?

Could you not use some server side script to get the HTML page and then A DOM Parser and XML writer to produce the XML document? In PHP this could be done fairly simply with Simple HTML DOM Parser and the SimpleXML library.